# How can I extract text from multiple web pages of which some pages have text under different tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract all the transcripts from this url - https://fangj.github.io/friends/

I have tried my code, but

- episode 217-223 does not get extracted fully.
- episode 302 none of the transcript gets extracted.
- episode 224, 921, 1015 (and many more) do not have one line per dialogue.
- and so on.

If I understand correctly, many of the web pages have different structure for the text which makes it hard for me to generalize the code, unless I am missing out on something here.

My objective is to get the text **as-is** from the web pages, into text files with the episode name as file name - i.e. `0101.txt`, `0310.txt` etc just like the url ending extension. Right now I have collected them all manually by `ctrl+a + ctrl+c + ctrl+v`. I wish to scrape it so that I can automate this process. Right now that alternative is to use `pyautogui` for this. But I prefer web scraping, if that is possible. I am open to other libraries in python if they exist.

**CODE**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fangj.github.io/friends/"

page_content = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

page_html = BeautifulSoup(page_content.content, "html.parser")

list_of_links = page_html.findAll('a')

list_of_hrefs = []
for href in list_of_links:
    if href.has_attr('href'):
        list_of_hrefs.append(href.attrs['href'])

episode_nos = []
for link in list_of_hrefs:
    episode_nos.append(link.split('/')[1].split('.')[0])

list_of_urls = []
for href in list_of_hrefs:
    list_of_urls.append(url+href)

for episode_no, one_url in enumerate(list_of_urls):
    episode_content = requests.get(one_url, timeout=5)
    episode_html = BeautifulSoup(episode_content.content, "html.parser")

    episode_dialogues = episode_html.findAll('p')

    with open('../../data/raw/{}.txt'.format(episode_nos[episode_no]), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for text in episode_dialogues:
            file.write(text.text.replace('\n', ' ') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the entire HTML tag text to get everything inside each episode link i.e. `select_one('html').text`.  That seems a lot easier.

You can use a css attribute = value selector with `^` operator (to state value of attribute starts with substring on right of `=` ) to gather all the initial episode links i.e. `[href^='season']`.

As making a lot of calls you can re-use connection with session. I believe multiprocessing might be a good idea here as well.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ftfy

session = requests.Session()

def makeSoup(url):
    res = session.get(url,timeout=5)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup_content = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    for style in soup_content(["style"]):
        style.decompose()
    return soup_content

url = "https://fangj.github.io/friends/"
soup = makeSoup(url)

links = [url + link['href'] for link in soup.select("[href^='season']")]
results = [[link.split('season/')[1].split('.html')[0], makeSoup(link).select_one('html').text] for link in links]

df = pd.DataFrame(results)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open('data/' + row[0] + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(ftfy.fix_text(row[1]))
```

You can then do what you need with the text retrieved.

Comment: Hi. This works. Two questions though if you don't mind.

(1) In 0124, page source shows "I don't&#151". How do I convert the "&#151" to "-" as displayed in the webpage so that I can write it like that to the file (and any other similar issues, how would I recognize it?) ? 

(2) May I edit your code to add writing to file? That would make the answer more complete.

Comment: This answer works to an extent. I still have to do a lot of manual cleaning up of the text, for example, (1) 0124 has a lot of "&#151". (2) 0821 has "&#146". (3) 1011- onwards has additional css formatting included in the extraction. I would like to have the texts as is. I will see if I can do something about it...

Comment: So now my only problem is the "&#151" and "&#146" characters. I use `with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file: file.write(data)` code. But, when I open in notepad++ it doesn't display the characters properly. This is a windows 7 system.

Comment: Hi, sorry have been asleep. You can https://pastebin.com/ where you are at with the code and I will have a look.

Comment: Hi. I used this https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to clean up the data before writing it to the file. Now when I open it works. I'll edit your answer and accept it.